# In which cases does the DataBinding.executePendingBindings should be used and when should be avoided?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, data-binding, android-databinding

I read about the [executePendingBindings()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ViewDataBinding.html#executePendingBindings()) method from different sources but was unable to find an exact answer when should it be used and when should be avoided.

The information that I was able to find was something like following : `executePendingBindings()` executes outstanding bindings immediately, not waiting till the next frame will be drawn. and also this method will perform all the bindings from the UI thread, otherwise `setVariable()` calls could be called from non-UI thread. if trigger `executePendingBindings()` for items of a huge list, those calls could affect `recyclerview's` performance.
That's all. no exact recommendations about it's usage.

So, the question: **in which cases does the executePendingBindings() should be called? and in which doesn't?**

Answer (score 0):

Apologies I miss understood the question initially.

I guess `executePendingBindings()` does exactly what it says it executes immediately without waiting for the next frame.

I think you should aim to use `executePendingBindings()` every time you are using data binding.

Having said that if you do not use `executePendingBindings()` your view may not get updated straight away as it will only execute the binding when the next frame is rendered. You may only notice the side effect when running on an older or slower device.

I think [this article](https://medium.com/google-developers/recyclerview-prefetch-c2f269075710) is a must read if you want to understand how the recycler view renders.

Another good read here [slow rendering](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/render).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. My question was only about the `executePendingBindings()` method and about it's use cases.